# Regarding JQuery Ajax to populate a selector dropdown,

Tags: php, jquery

Good day, I am new in PHP development and currently I am learning jQuery and Ajax. I want some opinion about a certain functionality I am trying to create.

In my main.php I have a selector dropdown:

```
<select id="months_dropdown" >
 <option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
```

And so on up to December. And I have another file called getEvent.php which I want to use jQuery Ajax to get data from. The ideal return value from getEvent.php should be a year and a month from these function

```
$year = date("Y");
$month = date("n");
```

My 2 questions are..

First, what should I use to get data from the other file? Is it .load() or .get()?
second is that, how do I transfer the month and year from getEvent to main? Do I set a return value?

I tried looking for tutorials with .get and .load, and most of them are used to populate  or

. Some of the samples just get data from .txt file or .asp.

I would like to learn more and I am willing to listen to any feedback or answers given. Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: So you want to select the option in your select with the value returned from your AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

At First, Why do you want to perform this by `ajax` if it can be done in `javascript Date Function`.

Also you can use `load or get or post` these all are shorthands of `$.ajax`.

Urls are

1. [Load](http://api.jquery.com/load)
2. [Get](http://api.jquery.com/get)
3. [Post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post)
4. [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

**For egs,**

```
$.ajax({
   url:'getEvent.php',
   data:{month:$('#months_dropdown').val()},
   type:'POST',
   success:function(data){
     alert(data);      
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the urls, let me read them first.

Yeah about that, I want to use ajax cause everytime someone uses the dropdown, it gets data from the server. At the same time, I want the dropdown part and my calendar to be populated automatically using data from the server. I apologize for not giving all the information, what Im planning to create is a dropdown menu and a calendar which shows different events.